# Change from php-mysqld to php-mysqlnd

Tags: mysql, mysqlnd

I have a `VPS` with centOS 6.3 installed on it, i want to change from `php-mysqld` to `php-mysqlnd` (native driver) for better performance.

But the problem is that i have a production website on the server with a huge database and phpmyadmin installed to take control of DBs web based. now i'm afraid that if i erase php-mysqld and the install php-mysqlnd i will lost DBs as well as users created for them and i have to config all of them again.

Is there anyway to keep my DBs , Users, Configs , ... during this change ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you think it could remove your database? It's an official extension, not a malware worm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i found it to be done so easily, as you only change the driver nothing needs to be change.

A simple yum erase php-mysqld and then yum install php-mysqlnd and a reboot will do it all and you don't need any backup nor any config change.