# Enable MySQLnd though a script

Tags: php, mysqli

guys! I have a problem about setting up MySQLnd though a script. My web hosting has supported PHP 5.4, but when I test my website, it showing an error

**Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in**

I have asked supporter of hosting, they said I may enable MySQLnd though a script.

Does anyone knows how to do that?

thanks!

Comment: They said you rubbish.

Comment: Google, that is the answer, possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321096/call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtget-result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid you will have to build something or what and PHP > 5.4 wont help..
This can be answer for you: [Change from php-mysqld to php-mysqlnd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900757/change-from-php-mysqld-to-php-mysqlnd)
Or you can try solution in comment on page http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php